# convert between Celsius and Fahrenheit using method

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

trying to convert using method, But when running it It doesn't do anything, what did I do wrong?

**java**

```
    ...
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = 0;

    switch selection {
    case 1:
        int k = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(celsius(k));
        break;

    case 2:
        int j = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(fahrenheit(j));
        break;
    }
    ...

public static double fahrenheit(double celsius) {
    double fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit = 9 / 5 * (celsius + 32);
    return fahrenheit;
}

public static double celsius(double fahrenheit) {
    double celsius;
    celsius = 5 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32);
    return celsius;
}

    ...
    plpStyleData.setStatus(ActionResponseStatus.SUCCESS);
    return plpStyleData;
}
```

Comment: "But when run it It doesn't do anything" How do you run it? As it stands, this isn't valid Java code; but even in that case, you'd get an error message when you try to compile it.

Comment: You're not getting the user's selection from the scanner.  You're just setting the selection to `0` and never changing it.  And since the switch has no case for `0`, none of the code in the switch runs.  This is why you should always have a `default` case.  You could print out something like "Invalid selection X" (where X is the selection), which would give you enough information to determine what the problem was.

Comment: Be aware that 9/5 will be 1 and 5/9 will be 0 since they are int's.  You need to use 9.0/5.0 to coerce the compiler into using doubles for your arithmetic

Comment: Semicolons are Good.  Proper indentation is Good.  Complete, compileable code snippets are Good.

Answer (score 1):

Because `selection = 0` so the switch won't go in the `case 1:` nor `case 2:` parts. You may want to set it to `input.nextInt()` so it will ask for an input first.

Answer (score 0):

This is not right:

fahrenheit = 9 / 5 * (celsius + 32)

(100C + 32) * 9/5 = 237.6F  Not correct.

Should be:

(100C * 9/5) + 32 = 212F

(212F - 32) * 5/9 = 100C, so that part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
212F to C
C = (F - 32) * 5/9.
C = (212 - 32) * 5/9.
C =  180 * 5/9. = 100.

100C to F
F = (C * 9/5.) + 32.
F = (100 * 9/5.) + 32.
F = (180 + 32) = 212
```

Now for some fun.  Need to get both in the form of `(T - offset)*scale`

```
C = (F - 32) * 5/9  

F = (C * 9/5) + 32
5/9F = C + 32*5/9 = C + 160/9.

F = (C + 160/9.)*9/5
```

The temp conversion generator. Take in the constants and generate the temp converters.

```
  BiFunction<Double,Double, DoubleFunction<Double>> temp = 
            (offset, scale) -> (t)->((int)((t - offset)*scale*1000)/1000.);

   DoubleFunction<Double> toCelsius = temp.apply(32., 5./9.);
   DoubleFunction<Double> toFahr = temp.apply(-160./9., 9./5.);

   System.out.println(toCelsius.apply(212));  //prints 100.
   System.out.println(toFahr.apply(37));      //prints 98.6
```